How to force Linux kernel to refresh disk modifications
I have a disk that was used by ceph, I used wipefs to clean it.
To make the system see that the disk is empty and can be used I have to reboot.
Is there a way to force the kernel to recognize those modifications without a reboot?
Before wipefs
# lsblk
...
sdc                                                                                                     8:32   0  100G  0 disk 
└─ceph--7c3decde--ca2b--4fe5--b330--412b38c3e402-osd--block--1a8fcc33--f299--4977--ad26--76b61c518966 252:0    0  100G  0 lvm

# wipfs -a -f /dev/sdc

After wipefs
# lsblk
...
sdc                                                                                                     8:32   0  100G  0 disk 
└─ceph--7c3decde--ca2b--4fe5--b330--412b38c3e402-osd--block--1a8fcc33--f299--4977--ad26--76b61c518966 252:0    0  100G  0 lvm

Need to reboot to refresh
# reboot
# lsblk
...
sdc

Regards.
